# Emacs Search exact word

Tags: emacs, xemacs

I'm working in verilog most of the time, and my favorite editor is emacs.

There a feature in vi (vim) I like but I don't know how to do it in emacs

I would like to do an exact word search, for example - let's say I have this text:

```
1. wire                   axi_bvalid = bvalid;
2. wire                   axi_bready; // assigned later
3. assign                 axi_cross_fifo_pop = axi_bvalid & axi_bready 
4. wire                   axi = 1'b1;
```

when searching for `axi` i would like to get match only on line 4.
 Today Ctrl-S search will match every instance of `axi`.

In vim the way to do it is press * on the word or /\.

Is there something similar in emacs?

Thanks allot, Jony

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Needs a regular-expression based search, for example

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `isearch-forward-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\_<axi\_>` <kbd>RET</kbd>

See Emacs Lisp Info-file,
node 34.3.1.3: Backslash Constructs in Regular Expressions

Running as command:

```
(defun my-re-search-forward (&optional word)
  "Searches for the last copied solitary WORD, unless WORD is given. "
  (interactive)
  (let ((word (or word (car kill-ring))))
    (re-search-forward (concat "\\_<" word "\\_>") nil t 1)
    (set-mark (point))
    (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
    (exchange-point-and-mark)))
```

Bind it to <kbd>C-c :</kbd> for example:

```
(global-set-key [(control c) (\:)] 'my-re-search-forward)
```

Comment: Hi Andreas,
Thanks for the great answer!

I have no clue about lisp, do you know how to write this and bind it to a key?

i mean i would like to have keymap that opens isearch-forward-regexp and i enter a text and its auto add the \_<my_text\>[^_]

Comment: @Jonathan Done. BTW isearch-forward-regexp is an command designed for interactive use. From inside Emacs Lisp re-search-forward quite often is useful.

Comment: Works for me without the `_`. Eg: `\<axi\>` instead of `\_<axi\_>`

Comment: @vineeshvs Think you are right, thanks. Just my habit to search for symbols.

Comment: This does not replace all the words if they show up, up part of the selected word to replace

Answer (score 11):

I think you are searching for the [Word Search](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Word-Search.html) feature, activated with `M-s w`.

You can use it in two ways: simply issue `M-s w`, then type the word to search.
Or to get something similar to `*` in vim, you can start a search with isearch, with `C-s C-w` (this searches for the word under cursor), then `M-s w` to toggle the search to whole word mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
but When i press M-s (Meta is my left alt) i get the goto line:

What should i do?

Comment: @Jonathan, perhaps you have `M-s` bound to something else. What does `C-h k M-s` give?

Comment: Chris,
`goto-line' is an interactive compiled Lisp function
  -- loaded from "/tools/install/common/xemacs-21.4.22/lisp/simple.elc"

how can i override it? or disable it?

Comment: This is the best answer. If for some reason `M-s w` is not bound to this (because something in your init file has changed it), try `C-s M-s w`. See the Emacs manual, node [`Word Search`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Word-Search.html). Of course, if you are using XEmacs then it might be different.

Comment: This also finds words like `_word`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a built-in function in Emacs that is equivalent to vim's <kbd>*</kbd>, but I did manage to write these two commands which may suite you:

```
(defun my-isearch-forward-word-at-point ()
  "Search for word at point."
  (interactive)
  (let ((word (thing-at-point 'word t))
        (bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word)))
    (if word
        (progn
          (isearch-mode t nil nil nil t)
          (when (< (car bounds) (point))
            (goto-char (car bounds)))
          (isearch-yank-string word))
      (user-error "No word at point"))))

(defun my-isearch-forward-symbol-at-point ()
  "Search for symbol at point."
  (interactive)
  (let ((symbol (thing-at-point 'symbol t))
        (bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol)))
    (if symbol
        (progn
          (isearch-mode t nil nil nil 'isearch-symbol-regexp)
          (when (< (car bounds) (point))
            (goto-char (car bounds)))
          (isearch-yank-string symbol))
      (user-error "No symbol at point"))))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-s ,") 'my-isearch-forward-word-at-point)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s .") 'my-isearch-forward-symbol-at-point)
```

As you see, I bound these command to <kbd>M-s ,</kbd> and <kbd>M-s .</kbd>.
Depending on your version of Emacs, you may be able to use the built-in command `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` (bound to <kbd>M-s .</kbd> by default).